# HTML 5 body tag to change color

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have this code, i need to change the body color, how can i do that?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Body bgcolor Attribute example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This webpage has colored background.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you do some research about basic css.

You can achieve that with this.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background: red; 
       }
      </style>
  
    <title>Body bgcolor Attribute example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This webpage has colored background.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that, There is a `style` tag before the title. You can style your HTML with CSS. Style tag contains your CSS code. Also, you can write your CSS in another file.

Comment: Your first sentence is a reason to downvote and close this question, not answer it. It has shown no attempt at research before asking here. [answer]